# Computing time from complexity classes

Tags: algorithm, big-o

`f` has a complexity class `O(N(logN)^2)`, for `N = 1000` the program runs in 8 seconds

Compute how long it will take to run when `N = 1,000,000`

I computed the time to be 32000 seconds, however I am confused because `N` grew 1000 times but the time increased by 4000 times. I thought that since this is a log function the factor increase of `N` should be less than that of time.

Are my calculations wrong or is there something I am not understanding?

Comment: _since this is a log function_ - it's N multiplied by log, so everything's alright. It's 1000 times for N and 4 times for (logN)^2, and these get multiplied, so your calculations seem to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"since this is a log function": no, this is a *linpolylog* function. Because there is a linear factor `N` and a polylog one `log^2(N)`, i.e. a polynomial of a logarithm.

So `N` grows by a factor `1000` and `log(N)` by a factor `2` (undisputably smaller than `1000`) thus `log^2(N)` by a factor `4`, for a total factor `4000`.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct. `N(logN)^2` grows a little faster than `N` does. Indeed, `N` factors both complexities but `(logN)^2` is crescent and unbound and so bigger than a constant reaching a big enough input.

Comment: You're thinking of `logN^2` which is *not* the same as `(logN)^2`